# R Open does not show/update to latest version of MRAN package

Tags: r, package, version, microsoft-r, dbplyr

I want to update an R package using Microsoft R Open via Microsoft R Server. I can see in MRAN package repo that the package version is 1.2.0 but when I try an update in RStudio it says all packages up to date although respective package is still on version 1.1.0 (dbplyr in my case). Why is R not updating the package? RStudio points to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server\R_SERVER`.

```
sessionInfo()
 #>R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
 #>Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 #>Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

 #Matrix products: default

 #>locale:
 #>[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
 #>[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

 #>attached base packages:
 #>[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 #>other attached packages:
 #>[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.5     RevoMods_11.0.0      MicrosoftML_1.5.0    mrsdeploy_1.1.2      RevoScaleR_9.2.1    
 #>[7] lattice_0.20-35      rpart_4.1-11        

 #>loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  #>[1] codetools_0.2-15       CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 foreach_1.4.4          grid_3.4.1             R6_2.2.0              
  #>[6] jsonlite_1.4           curl_2.6               iterators_1.0.8        tools_3.4.1            yaml_2.1.14           
 #>[11] compiler_3.4.1         mrupdate_1.0.1

packageVersion("dbplyr")
 #>‘1.1.0’
```

RStudio IDE has as mirror `Global (CDN) - RStudio` but I guess this is overruled by MRAN?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are running Microsoft R Server, and that has an R version of 3.4.1. I believe what happens is that when you try to upgrade using MRAN, the upgrade takes into consideration which version of R you're on - and (I believe again) the latest version of dbplyr for R 3.4.1 was 1.1.0. You can read more about snapshots and checkpoints [here](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility#checkpointpkg).

What you can do if you want is to install the package straight from the CRAN repo, using code something like so:

```
install.packages("dbplyr", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies=TRUE, lib = pkg.dir)
```

Hope this helps!

Niels

Comment: you can also override the default snapshot date to something more recent. eg: `setSnapshot(snapshotDate = "2019-04-10")`